# Vagrant waiting too long for ubuntu to boot

Tags: vagrant

Vagrant waits for ubuntu 12.04 to boot with:

```
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
```

The vm has long booted and not much is happening on it (I have turned GUI on and see all the activity icons are off) and yet vagrant waits for several minutes.

Is there a way to either fix vagrant boot detection with ubuntu or shorten some default times to achieve such effect?